# Views Filter on a subquery custom field

Tags: views

I've defined a global table, like this:

```
  $data['custom_test']['table']['group'] = t('Custom: Test');
  $data['custom_test']['table']['join'] = array(
    // #global is a special flag which let's a table appear all the time.
    '#global' => array(),
  );
```

Next I added a custom field:

```
  $data['custom_test']['test'] = array(
    'title' => t('Test'),
    'help' => t('Show test field'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'custom_test_handler_test_field',
    ),
```

With this I could now make a field handler; This field handler adds a subquery:

```
$this->query->add_field(NULL, "(QUERY)", '(FIELD)');
```

And with this I can output the result.

However, when I add a filter, (using a default filter handler), the query looks something like:

```
AND (.test BETWEEN '20' AND '30') ))
```

So what it does is that it tries to prefix a table, however there are no tables (since it's a subquery).

Is there someway I can fix this by configuration, without having to say build my own filter?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a filter class, since I use a subquery I needed to use `HAVING` rather than `BETWEEN`.

Comment: But how did you solve the problem of it referencing a table?